# Does the 'explode' effect has a maximum for the number of exploded blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('#global').show("explode", { number: 50}, 2000);
```

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work properly.
It looks like it's limited i never got more than 8/10 exploding blocks.

Are there a maximum ?
Any ideas ?

the explode effect is a native effect from the jquery-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jQuery [Effects Cheat sheet](http://jn.orz.hm/jquery/ui_effect.html)
shows to uses **pieces** instead of number

Answer (score 3):

I think the option you need to pass in is 'pieces', not 'number'.

```
$('#global').show("explode", { pieces: 50}, 2000);
```

Comment: No as shown on the jQuery documentation page:
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("explode", { number: 9 }, 1000);
});

Comment: Where did you see that ?
Because i just copied/pasted from JQuery website
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Explode
And it's written: 
"""
Hides the element by exploding it into 9 pieces.

$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("explode", { number: 9 }, 1000);
});
"""

Comment: Well it seems that you are right !
Thank you, but i'm still curious to know where did you get it ? 
Because it's not metionned anywere on the explode effects page on jquery website.

Comment: There, I fixed the documentation page.

Comment: I read the code that Dmitri posted, and it's reading 'pieces' from the options array.  I assumed that Dmitri copied those 2 lines and didn't type them himeself...

Comment: I was getting suspicious at the point you pointed that out. Odd that their documentation page worked too.

Yeah I copy and pasted it from the jqueryui.explode code file.

Comment: It's not odd, if the nothing is set for 'pieces' then it's set to 9 (3x3) as pointed out by yourself Dmitri. So they could have specified anything as the value for number and it wouldn't have mattered. I'll try to improve the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked out the code.

```
var rows = o.options.pieces ? Math.round(Math.sqrt(o.options.pieces)) : 3;
var cells = o.options.pieces ? Math.round(Math.sqrt(o.options.pieces)) : 3;
```

There does not seem to be a limit on the number of pieces. This statement just checks if you have passed in a number of pieces and if yes calculates rows and cells, otherwise it defaults to 9 pieces.

With 50 pieces being passed in, going through the calculation of Round(SquareRoot(50));
we get 7 rows and 7 columns. That should result in 49 pieces.

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer, i just checked out the code too, and indeed, there does not seem to be a limit...
And i still don't understand then...
Thanks for your answer anyway !

Comment: What is the size of the element?